# Exception caught by widgets library BoxConstraints has a negative minimum width

Tags: flutter, dart

Ok, so today I am runninng this program

```
class NumberVerifyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String page = 'number_verify';
  @override
  _NumberVerifyPageState createState() => _NumberVerifyPageState();
}

class _NumberVerifyPageState extends State<NumberVerifyPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));
    animation = CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController, curve: Curves.elasticInOut);

    animationController.forward();

    animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        animationController.reverse(from: 1.0);
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        animationController.forward();
      }
    });

    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                    width: animation.value * 200,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/doomapic.jpg'),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      'Hi There! Welcome  ',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.08),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 35, right: 20),
                child: IntlPhoneField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter your Phone Numbers',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.1),
              BottomFlatButton(
                onTap: () {},
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and I get the following error
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Container(padding: EdgeInsets(20.9, 0.0, 20.9, 0.0), constraints: BoxConstraints(w=-14.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity; NOT NORMALIZED), dirty):
BoxConstraints has a negative minimum width.

## The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=-14.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity; NOT NORMALIZED)
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Container file:///C:/Users/fredi/AndroidStudioProjects/dooma_app/lib/screens/otp_verify/number_verification_screen.dart:62:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid..throwError (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:517:9)
#1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid. (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:546:19)
#2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:565:6)
#3      new ConstrainedBox (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:2198:27)
#4      Container.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart:430:17)
...

Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...

Comment: Your container has a width of 0 when the animation starts. Adding the padding means it's going to have a negative width.

Comment: what do I do then @Abion47

Comment: You might try adding a `Math.min` call so that the width is never less than the padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the animation causes the container to exceed its boundary. Check the value of the [AnimationController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) with `animationController.value` and see if it matches the expected animation status. It seems that you're also calling `animationController.forward()` twice so you might also want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Without using darz you can implement your ouwn Failure,Success.

```
    // Base Result class
/// [S] represents the type of the success value
/// [E] should be [Exception] or a subclass of it
sealed class Result<S, E extends Exception> {
  const Result();
}

final class Success<S, E extends Exception> extends Result<S, E> {
  const Success(this.value);
  final S value;
}

final class Failure<S, E extends Exception> extends Result<S, E> {
  const Failure(this.exception);
  final E exception;
}
```

And in the Future:

```
    // 1. change the return type
Future<Result<Location, Exception>> getLocationFromIP(String ipAddress) async {
  try {
    final uri = Uri.parse('http://ip-api.com/json/$ipAddress');
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        // 2. return Success with the desired value
        return Success(Location.fromMap(data));
      default:
        // 3. return Failure with the desired exception
        return Failure(Exception(response.reasonPhrase));
    }
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    // 4. return Failure here too
    return Failure(e);
  }
}
```

Credits: Andrea Bizzotto and his fantastic blog codewithandrea.com -

Article: codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-exception-handling-try-catch-result-type.